# Llamar a una Ventana Modal desde una vista parcial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo una vista parcial en donde listo ciertos datos en forma de una tabla, quisiera tener por fila un botón de editar, pero no quiero que me lance a una nueva venta, sino que estos campos se puedan editar en un modal, pero honestamente no sé cómo hacer esto.

Parte de mi vista parcial, en donde tengo el boton de editar es esto.

```
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <td>
      <button class="btn btn-primary edit-radicado" data-id="@item.NumeroRecepcion">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>

        <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Estadistica", new {recepcion = item.NumeroRecepcion})" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
    </td>


    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FechaAudiria)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UsuarioRevision)
    </td>

    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnidadesSoportadas)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modmodelItemel => item.Devoluciones)
    </td>

}
```

Luego tengo un div donde deberia inserta el contenido de la vista parcial "Editar"

```
<div class="modal hide fade in" id="edit-person">
    <div id="edit-person-container"></div>
</div>
```

El js que tengo en el momento para llamar a la vista parcial "Editar" es este.

```
 $(".edit-radicado").click(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Estadistica/Edit',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { recepcion: id },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    //$(".edit-person-container").html(data);
                    $(".edit-person-container").load(data);
                    $(".edit-person").modal('show');
                }
            });
        });
```

Y la vista parcial Editar es esta.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Ahora, lo que no entiendo es por qué no me dibuja (muestra) el contenido que trae en el ajax en la div. De ante mano muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Cambia el `$(".edit-person-container").load` por `$("#edit-person-container").html` y en ningun lugar veo el boton con la clase edit-radicado, al asignar el evento `$(".edit-radicado").click` puede que no encuentre el elemento.

Comment: Hola @DanAlvarez, me equivoque al copiar el código de ejemplo (respecto al botón), ahora con lo que me sugieres de cambiar el load por html, ya lo había intentado con el mismo resultado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para cargar un modal de forma dinámica hay dos formas:

1. Cargar el modal de manera remota

   ```
   <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="@Url.Action("Edit","Estadistica")" class="btn btn-primary edit-radicado" data-id="@item.NumeroRecepcion">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   </a>
   ```

   esto implica, que tu vista debe tener el formato del modal

   ```
   <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
     <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
     Todo el contenido aquí del modal
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
   </div>
   ```
2. La siguiente forma es usando ajax:

   - Tener un contenedor en el cual se va a cargar el modal

     ```
     <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal"></div>
     ```
   - Detectar el `click` del boton(tal cual lo tienes en tu pregunta)

     ```
     //cargando la vista por una peticion post usando .load()
     $('#ElemPadre').on('click', '#ElemBoton', function(){
       var id = $(this).data('data-id');
       $('#myModal').load('@Url.Action("Edit","Estadistica") ?recepcion=' + id + '', function (){
         //Aquí podemos cargar o llamar las librerias que se puedan usar en el modal.

         //haciendo visible el modal después de cargar
         $('#myModal').modal('show');
       });
     })

     //cargando la vista por una peticion post usando .ajax()
     $('#ElemPadre').on('click', '#ElemBoton', function(){
       let valorId = $(this).data('id');
       $.ajax({
         url: '@Url.Action("Edit","Estadistica")',
         type: 'POST',
         data: { recepcion: id },
         success: function(data){
           $('#myModal').html(data);
           $('#myModal').modal('show');
         },
         error: function(xmlResponse){
           alert("Error en la solicitud del modal")
         }
       });
     })
     ```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes hacer es llamar a un fieldset que contenga el formulario de editado y que al momento de guardar, llame a un javascript que recopile los datos mediante un json, los envie al controller y realice la actualizacion, y que al momento de retornar una respuesta (true), realice un refresco de pagina, mostrandote los datos actualizados.

Este es un ejemplo que estoy usando y me funciona al 100%:

**boton que llama al modal**

```
<a data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" href="#Rechazar" class="button has-tip" id="btnRechazar" title="Rechazar">Rechazar</a>
```

**div "modal" que despliega el contenido del fieldset**

```
<div id="divModalLead" class='reveal-modal' data-reveal aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
        <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
    </div>
```

**Fieldset a desplegar en el modal**

```
<fieldset id="Rechazar" class="panel callout large-12">
    <h4>Modal</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-6 columns">
            <div id="otherType" >
                Comentario :

                @Html.TextArea("comentarioR", null, new { cols = "55", rows = "7" })
            </div>
            <ul class="stack-for-small secondary button-group round">
                <li><a href="#" class="button" onclick='(funcion de JS)' >Rechazar Oportunidad</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**Scripts**

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {

  $("#Rechazar").fadeOut();    //Oculta el fieldset
}

$("#btnRechazar").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var content = $("#Rechazar").html();
                $('#divModalLead').html('<a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>');
                $('#divModalLead').append(content);
                $('#divModalLead').foundation('reveal', 'open');
            });                  //Funcion que se ejecuta al presionar el boton "Rechazar"
)
</script>
```

imagenes del ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si estas perdido con el metodo Json para guardar los datos, me comentas y te ayudo :D

Comment: Hola @Ariel Ignacio, por lo que entiendo, ¿tiene el formulario de edición en la misma vista? ¿osea no tiene una vista parcial aparte?

Comment: @jeissoni22 Claro, es en la misma vista, pero lo invocas mediante un modal

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar debes poner el código donde llamas el modal dentro de la la misma vista donde llamas la Partial al igual que el Script donde lo llamas.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ModelEditar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog mod" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="myModalLabel"> Editar Persona</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="edit-person-container"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).on("click", ".editar ", function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
            var url = "@Url.Action("Edit", "Estadistica")/" + id;
            $("#modalEditar").load(url, function () {
                $("#PersonaId").val(id);
            });
        });
```

El botón dentro de la lista en la Partial de esta forma te funciona

```
<a id="persona_@item.Id" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModelEditar" class="btn btn-default btn-sm editar" href="javascript:;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
```

En el controlador para llamar el Modal tu método GET de esta forma

```
  public ActionResult Editar (int id)
    {
        var persona = db.Personas.Find(id);
        return PartialView("_EditarPartial", persona);
    }
```

Ya el Post si lo ajustas a tu necesidad.